# jQuery selectors for dynamically loaded HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery does not seem to be able to select a loaded HTML element. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="class name"  style="display: none;">
    <div id="submenuID" class="submenuID" />
    <script>
        loadHtmlUsingJavascript('parameter1', 'parameter2');
    </script>
</div>
```

The loaded HTML is a list of links. This is my JavaScript:

```
$("#submenuID li").addClass("active");
```

But it would not add the class. After some snooping around. I learn to use

```
$("#submenuID li").live('click', function() {
    $("#submenuID li").addClass("active");
});
```

However, it does not work until I click on the link a second time.

Comment: `live` needs to be called on an element that is static on the page. You could fix your problem by doing `$(document).live` or possible `$("#submenuID").live()`. However, that's deprecated, use the answer that we've linked to when closing your question, which is what Jorge Silva suggested http://stackoverflow.com/a/25772585/227299

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the following:

```
$("#submenuID").on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

First, the jQuery `.live` function is deprecated since jQuery 1.7 (http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Also, you should be listening for `li` methods inside the `#subMenuID` element.

Comment: ...assuming JQuery 1.7+